# console.log(variable) is duplicating itself with multiple passes

Tags: jquery, variables, console, duplicates

First and foremost, this is literally my first semi-tiered menu I'm trying to make from scratch. If this code looks sloppy, please recommend any tips for minimizing it.

TO THE POINT:
Code works fine.
Line: 242
Live @:
http://www.sinsysonline.com/repair/form_sinsys2.html

For some reason, it is setting my variable sysStr (which is the blue title display when the system is clicked on) multiple times.

To observe what I'm talking about, move through the flow:
Click a system, click a location, select the down arrow on system type, click a system, and click a location.


I have it console.log(sysStr) to see what it's establishing and for every workflow it is logging +1 items. (view in firebug or developer tools console while working through workflow).


BTW: To prove it works, I only have two forms:
*Desktop -> Pick-Up
*Desktop -> Drop-Off

**Why does it console.log(sysStr) multiple times for every workflow?** I'm stumped :/

TO THE POINT:
Code works fine.
Line: 242
Live @:
http://www.sinsysonline.com/repair/form_sinsys2.html

```
<script>
(function() {

var systemDiv = $('div#repair_system'),
    locationDiv = $('div#repair_location'),
    systemH2 = $('h2#system_type'),
    locationH2 = $('h2#location_type'),

    systemSel = $('span#system_selected'),
    systemChange = $('a#system_redo'),
    locationSel = $('span#location_selected'),
    locationChange = $('a#location_redo');

    $("a").click(function() { return false; });

    $('div#repair_system img').on('click', function() {

        var sysStr = $(this).attr('alt');

        systemDiv.slideUp();
        systemSel.show();
        systemSel.text(sysStr);
        systemChange.show();
        locationDiv.slideDown();

        systemChange.on('click', function() {
            $(this).hide();
            systemDiv.slideDown();
            systemSel.hide();
            locationDiv.slideUp();
            locationSel.hide();
            locationChange.hide();
            $('div#repair_forms div').hide();
        });

        locationChange.on('click', function() {
            $(this).hide();
            locationSel.hide();
            systemDiv.slideUp();
            systemSel.show();
            systemChange.show();
            locationDiv.slideDown();
            $('div#repair_forms div').hide();
        });

        $('div#repair_location img').on('click', function() {
            var locStr = $(this).attr('alt'),
                sysStr = systemSel.text();

            locationDiv.slideUp();
            locationSel.show();
            locationSel.text(locStr);
            locationChange.show();
            $('div#repair-' + sysStr + '-' + locStr).show();

            console.log(sysStr);
        });
    });

    $("img.a").hover(
        function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "fast");
        },
        function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");

    });

})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because in your HTML you have two img tags in each of these divs
i.e.

```
<div class="glow">   <img src="images/remote-icon-bw.jpg" class="a" alt="remote" style="opacity: 1;">   <img src="images/remote-icon.jpg" class="b" alt="remote">   <h2>Remote</h2> </div>
```

try adding a class to one of the images say img-click i.e.

```
<div class="glow">   <img src="images/remote-icon-bw.jpg" class="a img-click" alt="remote" style="opacity: 1;">   <img src="images/remote-icon.jpg" class="b" alt="remote">   <h2>Remote</h2> </div>
```

now change this line

```
 $('div#repair_system img').on('click', function() {
```

to

```
 $('div#repair_system img.image-click').on('click', function() {
```

Comment: No result? Updated live site after response to exact code you had mentioned. It still stacks the console.log(sysStr) for every action. So the 18th time in the full workflow (from changing system type after everything is selected) it will console.log(sysStr) 18 times. Not to mention the bottom ones work fine with the same styling as the first tier :-P

Answer (score 0):

Well, for the sake of simplicity, I just ended up building it into the site anyway.

The duplicate console.log of variable sysStr would still be helpful for identification:

http://www.sinsysonline.com/repair/contact.html (whole page)
http://www.sinsysonline.com/repair/form.php (form alone)

Feedback on markup and jQuery flow would be appreciated (hit me!).